# Flutter firestore stream denied exception

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my flutter app I have an open stream that is listening to changes on a document on firestore. If I log the user out i receive the following exception:

```
[Firestore]: Listen for Query(THE_DOC_PATH) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
I/System.out( 6117): com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

I have a few questions

1. Does the close the stream for me automatically?
2. Are there any downsides to this happening? e.g. using extra reads on the doc or firestore rules
3. Should i manually be closing the stream before the user signs out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the close the stream for me automatically?

Yes.  After an error like this, there will be no more items emitted from the stream.

> Are there any downsides to this happening? e.g. using extra reads on the doc or firestore rules

There are no extra costs, if that's what you're implying.

> Should i manually be closing the stream before the user signs out?

Typically, yes. But that's a matter of opinion, and it's up to you.

Comment: Hi Doug, Thanks for the clear answer! Am I okay to call .cancel() on the stream after it has thrown the exception in my question? e.g. In the firebaseAuth user state change listener.

Comment: I don't see why it would cause a problem.  Try it and see what happens.

Comment: Theres no exception so i guess its fine